# MATLAB phased.URA.step: where is my phaseshift?

Tags: matlab

I want to get the sensor array complex response ratios from an angle. I try to use `phased.URA()` and its method `step(freq, angle)`, but it gives me equal numbers for each element for any angle. Where is my phaseshift, dudes?

Here is a small example:

```
ant_array = phased.URA();
disp(ant_array.step(3e8, [45; 0]));
```

It gives me a result:

```
  1
  1
  1
  1
```

Can anyone tell me, what does it mean and how can I use `angle` parameter correctly?

Comment: To be honest I don't have absolutely any idea of the topic but: are you sure that is not the right answer? The example in Matlab also does give 4 ideantical nnumbers.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if MATLAB itself gives the correct answer.